# Flex 4.5 - Assigning a variable after service data load

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, mxml, flex4.5

I have generated a service call to a service called ServiceName.getService() - I can successfully pull data displayed inside mxml layout elements, but, instead of displaying it, I just want to assign it to a global.

I always get an error on the second line below - apparently the value has not been fetched yet. I have also tried adding a listener, and setting the global value on COMPLETE, but that is apparently never called. (I am guessing this generated service call stuff does not actually trigger a COMPLETE?)

**Short question is: how do you simply assign a variable after you have loaded it via a service data call. (Not just HTTP)**

```
getServiceResult.token=ServiceName.getService();
GlobalVars.variablename = getServiceResult.lastResult.variablename;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I always get an error on the second line below - apparently the value
>   has not been fetched yet.

That is correct.  In Flex / Flash the remote server calls asynchronous.  That means your second line--to set the value--is potentially running before the service call has executed.

You should set up a [result](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/events/ResultEvent.html#RESULT) handler on the service call.  This is most likely the same thing you did when you got things to work for display.

Like this:

```
getServiceResult.token=ServiceName.getService();
getServiceResult.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,myServiceResult);
```

And elsewhere in your code:

```
protected function myServiceResult(event:ResultEvent):void{
 GlobalVars.variablename = event.results.variablename;
}
```

When you talk about adding a listener on complete, I'm not sure what you refer to.  Do you mean creationComplete?  or updatecomplete? Or applicationComplete?   Or something else altogether.

Comment: yes, ResultEvent.RESULT was what I was looking for - ResultEvent.COMPLETE was not triggering